# How to show a loading screen while we fetch data from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

Here I want to show the spinkit or any some text while we fetch data from firebase.
Now i am not getting the spinkit while i am signing in. So please help me.

```
TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        FutureBuilder(
                          future: loadFirebase(),
                          builder: (context,datasnap){
                            if(datasnap.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting){
                              return SpinKitRotatingCircle(
                                duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                                size: 50,
                              );
                            }
                            else if(datasnap.connectionState==ConnectionState.active){
                              return SpinKitRotatingCircle(
                                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                                size: 50,
                              );
                            }
                            else if(datasnap.connectionState==ConnectionState.none){
                              return Text('nulll');
                            }
                            else return Text('else null');

                          }
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Sign-in',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 17,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                  ),
```

Below is my loadfirebase function which i used in onpressed.

```
 Future<void> loadFirebase() async {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: User_email_id.text, password: user_Passowrd.text)
        .then((value) => {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Page_First())
      )
    }).catchError((e){
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e!.message);
    });
  }
```

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61664222/flutter-futurebuilder-not-rebuilding-when-user-logs-into-firebase

Answer (score 0):

You need to await the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` call in your `loadFirebase` function:

```
Future<void> loadFirebase() async {
  try {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: User_email_id.text, password: user_Passowrd.text);
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Page_First());
  } catch (error, trace){
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e!.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried using await , but that is also not working @Stefan

Comment: What exactly was not working?

Comment: I am not getting the Loading Screen ,while awaiting for the firebase signing i am on the same screen and then after successfully signing in the next screen appears on which i am navigating